# Implementing a ChannelOutboutHandler in Netty in conjunction with WebSocket

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 4.0.19, and trying to implement a ChannelOutboudHandler for a scenario where a Netty Client acts as a proxy between a client-application and server-application. It looks something as follows

< Client Application > ---(web socket) --------> < Web Socket server = forwards data => Netty Client > ----[netty pipeline]---[out-bound handler 1]----> < Server Application >

There are two initial messages that are communicated between the Client Application and the Server Application, which requires two types to ChannelOutboundHandler. 
The Netty client which sits between the Client and the Server Application, is responsible to 
detect the validity authority of the messages exchanged. Thus it's reads the message being passed and performs a check on the content of the message, and once verified it will establish a relay communication between client and server applications.

The first outbound handler (the interesting part) looks like this:

```
@Override
public void write(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
        final Object msg,
        final ChannelPromise promise)
          throws Exception {
   try {
    buff = (ByteBuf) msg;
       buff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

       // TODO add the logic for readable bytes

       ByteBuf helloBuff = null;
        try {
            helloBuff = buff.readBytes(Msg.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            Msg msg = new Msg(helloBuff);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            buff.release();
            if (helloBuff != null) {
                helloBuff.release();
            }

            log.error("Error while converting to a hello msg", e);
            return;
        }

        ctx.writeAndFlush(helloBuff, promise)
                .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.FIRE_EXCEPTION_ON_FAILURE)
                .addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                        if (future.isSuccess()) {
                            ctx.channel().flush();
                        } else {
                            future.channel().close();
                        }
                    }
                });

       final ChannelPipeline p = ctx.pipeline();
       p.replace(this,AnotherHandler.class.getSimpleName(),
               createAnotherHandler(ID));
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Error occured", e);
} finally {
  buff.release();
}
```

}

And the second outbound handler looks pretty similar, only just that it handles a different kind of a message and adds more checks.

Finally my questions:

1] The second outbound handler in certain scenarios, does not get activated. It works when
have breakpoints in my test. I am considering to add Encoders to convert the Object to ByteBuff with adding readableBytes() check. Will that help? Or is there something I am missing in my above code?

2] The write in my second handler does not reach the server application. How can I debug this issue, any pointers will be helpful.

3] I notice some "ghost" data being forwarded from my websocket server to the netty client, even when the client application does not write anything. I am not sure where does this data
come from?

Please feel free to answer 1 or many of my questions above.

Prasanna

Comment: @norman-maurer I have read/watched most of your posts/presentations/examples, which is very helpful. But I was not able to find a good example for ChannelOutboudHandlers, can you point me to one?

Comment: @trustin I have read your posts and examples too. So please feel free to share some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answers to my questions:

1] Netty doesn't allow to add encoders in conjunction with ChannelOutboundHandler(s), so kept the existing solution where I perform the check for enough readable-bytes.

2] I had a bug in my test as I was trying to read the response at wrong end.

3] There is no "ghost" data, I found out that the test-framework that is being used was sending the extra data.